# Facebook Open Graph, how to get Comments array with recent ones first?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I querying a comments box on this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=10150692213226360

I don't quite get which comments the array contains. It doesn't seem to contain all. Anyhow I only need the latest comment. I don't care about the rest. So how should I write the URL so that I get it first on the array, or only the last comment so I'm able to parse it easily with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

```
SELECT   id,
         username,
         fromid,
         time
FROM     comment
WHERE    object_id = 10150692213226360
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

[Sample](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+text%2C+fromid+from+comment+where+object_id%3D10150692213226360&access_token=AAAEhdAxqE1EBAIZBcdUxGI6U47BgFKocZCYZCMUOInRvcrficRY4uuLfgmkYUNnmZCy3FSFLv0W0SsoX2zYx0i3LGv5QB8ZA8pPIG8tWBMaJGIjvKHOiL&format=json)

About **username** in comment table

> The user name that a user entered when they posted a comment. In these
>   cases, the fromid returned will be 0. Note that user names for valid
>   users are not returned here.

Hope this helps